# Check if a xml tag contain comments

Tags: java, xml

Without using a XML parser libary, How do I check if a xml tag contain comments ?

Following is the code I came up with, It works for the comments that are contained inside a tag, but not a tag that's already nested within another comment.

```
<ppn>750000015</ppn>
<ppn>750007015</ppn>
<ocn></ocn>
<!-- <inst> VU@</inst> is commented -->
```

Java Code:

```
 public static List<String> getTagList(String xml, String tag) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (xml != null && tag != null) {

            String startMarker = "<" + tag + "[\\s>]";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(startMarker);
            String endMarker = "</" + tag + ">";
            // Find the start of all such tags:
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                int startIndex = matcher.start();
                int endIndex = xml.indexOf(endMarker, matcher.start()) + endMarker.length();
                result.add(xml.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a parsing library ?  You don't want to reinvent a wheel !

Comment: Yeah company uses a standard parser with all sort of issues and i dont want to use that. Neither they let me use a parser.. I am sure there should be someway to alter this piece of code i have and add that part .

Comment: You need to build a minimal state machine. You can't hack around that code.

Comment: String newXML = xml.replaceAll("(?s)<!--.*?-->", ""); ". This newXML can be then used in the above code for pattern matching. In that way comments are no more in the input. There are always hacks

Comment: If they won’t let you use a parser, will they let you use [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)?

Answer (score 1):

> Without using a XML parser libary

By definition, anything that reliably detects comments within XML elements is parsing the XML. So your choice is between using an XML parser library that does the job properly, and writing your own XML parser that does the job badly.

If your boss won't let you use an off-the-shelf XML parser for this task, then they are incompetent; and recommendations for dealing with incompetent bosses are out of scope for this forum.

Comment: We need a "this is a management issue" Close/Off Topic reason :D